# How to query my sqlite database with a variable

Tags: java, android, sqlite, filter

I want to show the month i have chosen in a textview. To do this i have a spinner, and when i select a month in the spinner this should find all the data i have for this specific month.
I am not sure of how to filter the query with a variable, or how to pass the variable from my Start.java class to my KilometerSQL.java class.

Since I'm not using a intent to go to the Kilometer.java class i don't know how i can pass the variable.

Here is my Start.java class

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int arg2,
        long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String month = parent.getSelectedItem().toString(); //This is my month variable

    KilometerSQL spinner = new KilometerSQL(this);
    spinner.open();

    String dataSpinner = KilometerSQL.spinnerData();
    spinner.close();

    logbog.setText(dataSpinner);

}
```

And here is my KilometerSQL.java class

```
public static String spinnerData() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String [] columns = new String []{ KEY_DAY, KEY_MONTH, KEY_YEAR, KEY_KILOMETER, KEY_LOCATIONS};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_MONTH, null, null, null, null);
    String result = "";

    int iDay = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_DAY);
    int iMonth = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_MONTH);
    int iYear = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_YEAR);
    int iKilometer = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_KILOMETER);
    int iLocations = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_LOCATIONS);

    for (c.moveToFirst();!c.isAfterLast();c.moveToNext()){
        result = result + c.getString(iDay) + "-" + c.getString(iMonth) + "-" + c.getString(iYear) + " " + c.getString(iKilometer) + " " + c.getString(iLocations) + "\n";
    }

    return result;
}
```

I haven't had any luck using answers similar to mine from other users.

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**In your Start.java class:**

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, KilometerSQL.class);
i.putExtra("KEY",YourData);
```

**In KilometerSQL.java class**

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if(extras !=null) {
    String value = extras.getString("KEY");
}
```

/`/Declare ur Textview here and set text to value`

**EDIT**
Did u try above or you can also try  `spinnerData(dataSpinner)`  in start class and change `String spinnerData(String dataSpinner)` in killometerSql class

**Start Class**

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int arg2,
        long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String month = parent.getSelectedItem().toString(); //This is my month variable

    KilometerSQL spinner = new KilometerSQL(this);
    spinner.open();

    String dataSpinner = KilometerSQL.spinnerData();//you said u want to pass from start to killometer ..Whats this line doing though
    spinner.close();

    logbog.setText(dataSpinner);
    spinnerData(month);


}
```

**Killometer class**

```
 public static String spinnerData(String KEY_MONTH) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String [] columns = new String []{ KEY_DAY, KEY_MONTH, KEY_YEAR, KEY_KILOMETER, KEY_LOCATIONS};
        Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_MONTH, null, null, null, null);
        String result = "";

        int iDay = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_DAY);
        int iMonth = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_MONTH);
        int iYear = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_YEAR);
        int iKilometer = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_KILOMETER);
        int iLocations = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_LOCATIONS);

        for (c.moveToFirst();!c.isAfterLast();c.moveToNext()){
            result = result + c.getString(iDay) + "-" + c.getString(iMonth) + "-" + c.getString(iYear) + " " + c.getString(iKilometer) + " " + c.getString(iLocations) + "\n";
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Can i use that when KilometerSQL is only containing my database? I mean i am not using an intent for the KilometerSQL class else

Comment: String dataSpinner = KilometerSQL.spinnerData();//you said u want to pass from start to killometer ..Whats this line doing though

Comment: Just to be sure, my kilometerSQL is not an activity. Therefore i am wondering if i can use intents? I haven't tried the intent thing yet, was just wondering. Thank you for your time.